# default extensions in devcontainers in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I try to understand the way vscode devcontainer is working.

I created a devContainer ("create a new dev container" -> using nodejs image). I see a mount for my workspace and another one for /vscode .

I installed some vscode extensions in the container.

Now I create a second container the same way using the same image (but another workspace mount of course), and the extensions arent't installed in the containers.

/vscode mount seem to be the same as in the first devContainer, if you look inside you can see the extensionCache with the installed app of the first devContainer.

I know I can set `"dev.containers.defaultExtensions"` but My question is more about where does the informations of the active extensions are ? As its not into devcontainer.json

And eventually, is there a way to set `"dev.containers.defaultExtensions"` by languages ?

Comment: You can add "extension by language" in the settings section: devcontainer.json=>customizations": {"vscode": { extensions": [...myExtensionslist   ],{"settings": {"files.associations": {"*.ext": "language-name" , ...

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela , If I edit the devcontainer.json inside the container, it'll not be applicable for another new container.